# MultiTenancy with ReactiveCrudRepository

Tags: spring, spring-data, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

I have a Spring boot webflux application. Its a SAAS application and there will be multiple organization and multiple users from each organization.

So, I store org_id in each table and apply

> where org_id=?

in each select, update and delete query.

For Ex:-

```
Table:-  organization
Fields :- org_id, name, ...

Table:- user
Fields :- usr_id, org_id, ...

Table:- schedule
Fields :- schedule_id, usr_id, org_id, ...
```

Here, I write custom query like below.

```
@Query("select * from schedule where schedule_id = $1 and org_id = $2")
Flux<Schedule> findById(int scheduleId, int orgId);
```

Is there any built in support for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such kind of support out of box.